# How to connect mongodb to shopify with limited api calls?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, request, shopify

*Shopify has limited number of API calls.* 
I have an e-commerce website where each seller will be using an external application on node.js to store data in MongoDB external to Shopify. Now, this data has to be stored in the Shopify database but the API calls are limited. Is there a way to club these calls before throwing it to Shopify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API call limitations are documented in details in [Shopify Docs for API Limits](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/rest-admin-api-rate-limits)

The default settings are as follows:

- Bucket size: 40
- Leak rate: 2/second

Shopify Plus

- Bucket size: 80
- Leak rate: 4/second

You can use [Shopify API Node.js Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node) to send Shopify API requests. This module provides you the options like autolimit that automatically takes care of Shopify API limits.

Example code:

```
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');

const shopify = new Shopify({
  shopName: 'your-shop-name',
  apiKey: 'your-api-key',
  password: 'your-app-password',
  autoLimit: true
});

// call Shopify api
```

Comment: I understand this, however, is there a method to club the api calls and then send them to shopify? For example 10 vendors (sellers) make 20 products each in 1 minute to my external mongodb database, how can i club this new data and send it to shopify?

Comment: No there is not. Shopify does not provide any bulk add or update API. You would have to process each record separately.

Comment: @ArpanJain Shopify recently launched Bulk GraphQL API which might suit your need. https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/bulk-operations